# X11 key press translator

Tags: x11

I would like to make a key press translator that would "convert" one key press to another, eg. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> would be translated to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. I would like it to make "gobal"; to make it work in any application.

As a proof of concept I'm experimenting with the code below but it doesn't work. The problem is that when I capture a key press I send out another key press that is again captured by my code... I'm getting an infinite loop (the counter is there only to break out of the infinite loop).
How should I send out key press event from a key press event handler?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <xdo.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>

int main(void)
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0x0);
    XEvent ev;
    int counter;
    xdo_t *xdo = xdo_new(NULL);



    XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), False, 
        GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync,CurrentTime);

    for(counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);

        if(ev.type == KeyPress) {
            XUngrabKeyboard(dpy, CurrentTime);
            printf("%d %d\n", ev.xkey.keycode, ev.xany.send_event);
            xdo_keysequence(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, "A", 0);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `xmodmap`?

Comment: Something very similar. But in some cases I would like to send out many key-presses instead of one. And there is the case when Ctrl+j would act as pressing the Shift key without releasing it. Some other key would send the release event. Not sure if xmodmap can do it. I'll check it out.

Comment: Hotkeys are usually implemented with `XGrabKey`, not `XGrabKeyboard`. This can work in simple cases, byt maybe not if you wish *Ctrl+j would act as pressing the Shift key without releasing it*. You may also want to check `xkbcomp` which is the keyboard configuration tool of modern X11.

Comment: You should be able to distinguish between real keyboard events and your own, generated ones by checking the 'send_event' flag in the XKeyEvent; this flag will be true for "synthetic" events that where injected using SendEvent.